# pharagraph display in line by line within 3 line

Tags: php

i have a one string of 75 charater and it display in 3 line how i display in 3 line in php pl help

Comment: Please give lots more detail about what you mean: write the code you have so far, what it does, and what you would like it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you are looking for [wordwrap](http://uk.php.net/wordwrap)

```
<?php
// a string with 75 characters
$x = str_repeat('x', 75); 

echo wordwrap($x, 25, '<br />', true);
```

edit: if your string contains whitespace wordwrap() might break the string into smaller pieces.
Then you need something like [str_split](http://php.net/str_split).

```
<?php
// a string with 75 characters including spaces
$x = str_repeat('x y', 25); 
echo join('<br />', str_split($x, 25));
```